# popup dialog not working after Migrate to Androidx

Tags: java, android, androidx

after migrating to androidx, the custom pop-up dialog is not working.
this is how I write the popup dialog layout, everything is working fine before migrating to androidx if u were answering kindly explain the reason for this issue. just showing a transparent screen when I initialize this dialog.

```
popupdialogSR.setContentView(R.layout.popup_subscribe);
    buyQr = popupdialogSR.findViewById(R.id.buttonBuyQr);
    scanQr = popupdialogSR.findViewById(R.id.buttonScanQr);
    gPay = popupdialogSR.findViewById(R.id.buttonGPAY);
    popupdialogSR.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    popupdialogSR.show();
```

layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_270sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/overlay_darkblur">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_160sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/applogo"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:text="@string/subscibe_popupcontent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonBuyQr"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_savechanges"
                android:text="@string/buy_qr"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonScanQr"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonScanQr"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_savechanges"
                android:text="@string/scan_qr"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonGPAY"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/google_payicon"
                android:background="@drawable/button_signin"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:elevation="11dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonScanQr"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If remove `popupdialogSR.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`, what will show?

Comment: i tried this but its just showing an small vertical line of Height 120dp and Width 10dp

Comment: how you define `popupdialogSR` ? Also post your `dimens.xml`.

Comment: using a library for dimens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the XML layout, i just changed the hieght and width to custom size, its just working fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="@dimen/_260sdp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_220sdp"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;


popupdialogSR = new Dialog(mContext);
popupdialogSR.setContentView(R.layout.popup_subscribe);
popupdialogSR.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
buyQr = popupdialogSR.findViewById(R.id.buttonBuyQr);
scanQr = popupdialogSR.findViewById(R.id.buttonScanQr);
gPay = popupdialogSR.findViewById(R.id.buttonGPAY);
```

If this will not work post your layout as well

Comment: not working , these imports alredy there, i will send xml for this.